# Jasper Reports pdf export rendering garbage characters in graphs

Tags: pdf

Using CentOS 7, Icinga2 2.7.5, MariaDB 5.5.56, Icinga Reports 1.10.0. 
I see no error in the catalina.out file but that's probably not where I need to be looking.

[image]

Comment: I installed ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64 and restarted Jasper. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64 and restarted Jasper. Problem solved.